D&D 5e 2024 Working Group and Question Collection
The new core books for D&D 5e are to be released in the coming months:



Book
Release Date




2024 Player's Handbook
September 17, 2024


2024 Dungeon Master's Guide
November 12, 2024


2025 Monster Manual
February 18, 2025



As Wizards of the Coast is marketing this as a revision, rather than a replacement, of the 5e core rules, we unfortunately do not have the clear cut distinction we would have with a properly new system. I think it prudent to get out ahead of some of the problems that are likely to arise when the new books drop and we begin receiving questions. To this end, I have a created a chat room for long form discussion:

D&D 5e 2024 Working Group

The purpose of this chat room is to collaboratively develop some guidance for handling anticipated problems. What problems though? That's where you come in. In answers to this question, please provide questions you would like answered by the working group, or any anticipated issues you would like to see some guidance for ahead of the releases.
In a few weeks, I will work with all of our collaborators to synthesize our discussions into some helpful guidance, which, of course, will be subject to change when the books drop and we see a need for adjustment.

Your followup post: Guidance proposals for D&D 5e 2024

(Note: this answer is just for collecting a list of questions/discussion points. Please direct any responses/suggestions to the D&D 5e 2024 Working Group chat room instead.)
Question List

[01] What should the new tag be, dnd-5e-2024, or something else?
[02] Should we keep the dnd-5e tag, or retag it? To what? dnd-5e-2014? (Using mod tools to get all 25,000+ questions done in one fell swoop).
[03] If we retag, should we drop the dnd-5e, or should we alias it to a version? Which version? When -- immediately, or in the future when people essentially will mean the 2024 version when they just refer to 5e?
[04] Or should dnd-5e become a tag that refers to any of the 5e editions? (2014, 2024, a future one...)?
[05] Should we encourage updating older dnd-5e questions with additional information of how things are changed in the 2024 version, or that they have not changed? Or should we consider all questions about the 2014 version specific to that and discourage such updates? What are the pro's and con's?
[06] Should there be an additional, special tag for questions that have to do with migration issues between versions, or with mismatch issues of using old splat books or modules with the new version? If so what should it be? Or should we just tag those with the new version tag, the old version tag, and maybe the tag of the splat-book or module in question?
[07] How should (new) questions be tagged that aren't about core rule books, but about suplement books that are valid for both version, i.e. Fizban's Treasury? Should everything that came out before the new  core books automatically refer to the 2014 version or should the question asker clarify which revision they are using?
[08] Is there a higher expectation for specifying sub-edition for rules mechanics questions? That is, "How do rangers work?" absolutely needs a 5e-2014 or 5e-2024 tag. But can a problem-player question get by while just tagged as 5e?
[09] What should querents be expected to say about which 5e they are asking about? How should they be informed of this expectation? How do we apply / respond to "don't guess the system" when someone does not indicate which version of 5e they are asking for? (for example, if the querent has not specified, would an answer outlining both possibilities be acceptable, or are all answers on hold until OP has clarified? Would an answer saying, "you don't specify which 5e this question is about, but it doesn't matter because the answer is the same" be acceptable?)
[10] Once the new PHB is released people will inevitably be using it together with the old DMG and MM, basically playing a mixed version. How should those questions be tagged? Jeremy Crawford even explicitely said that this approach is possible in this recent interview, though he recommends using the other new books, once they are released.
[11] If the D&D Beyond public version of the PHB rules gets updated to the 2024 PHB content without preserving older web pages, what should we do to address the legions of broken links that will arise on 5e-2014 questions and answers?


@Kirt Changing the numbers completely defeats the purpose of using numbers. Please don’t do that. The whole point is to be able to refer to the the question by number in the chat.

Are these meant to be answered by people on the answer? That seems extremely unusual and bad. I'm referring to KS's recent edit

@Exempt-Medic Yeah, this is just question/discussion point collection. Suggestions and responses belong in the chat. Thanks for the roll back.

I have been in a running discussion at GitP about the new PHB as various "reveals" by selected WotC sycophants (like Treantmonk) are made public.  There is a lot of reference to the UA.  It will be important to the quality of our Q & A that we filter out "this is what it said in the UA docs" versus "this is what it says in the PHB" when that tome is published.

As a service to our readers, we must make a new tag for that material.  dnd-5e-2024 is good.

A link to the followup post: Guidance proposals for D&D 5e 2024
